# How can I get the user Inputs and print it in a single row?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, input, user-input

I want to add an Item with **(name color and price)** however when I try it adds them like that. It should make a row such as **PHONE - Color: 0 - Price: 1000** instead of it displays three things. I tried to make a one method but it did not work too. How can I write the code in order to get these inputs on a line.

```
</div>
{props.options.length === 0 && <p className="widget__message">Please add a Product to get started!</p>}
{
  props.options.map((option, index) => (
    <Option
      key={option}
      optionText={option}      
      count= {index + 1}
      handleDeleteOption={props.handleDeleteOption}
    />     
  ))     
}
{
  props.colors.map((color, index) => (
    <Option        
      colorText = {color}
      count= {index + 1}
      handleDeleteOption={props.handleDeleteOption}
    />
  ))     
}

{
  props.prices.map((price, index) => (
    <Option       
      priceText = {price}          
      count= {index + 1}
      handleDeleteOption={props.handleDeleteOption}
    />
  ))  
}
```

export default Options;

Comment: To be honest, from your question, I have very little idea what you want. Can you please show or explain clearly what it is you're trying to do compared to what you have?

Comment: @zfrisch I would like to get inputs from the user by text ares. I can get the inputs and it shows the added product-color-price as 3 rows. It should be a single line for an added item. You can get the project and try it at https://github.com/ErkAydogan/React

Comment: Oh, I see. Where is your code that shows what happens when the user clicks add option?

Comment: It is the handleAddOption function at AddOption.js @zfrisch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what's happening is that you are printing the whole array so instead of getting the desire result of one of each you get first all of one type and then all of the other.

One approach can be:

```
</div>
{props.options.length === 0 && <p className="widget__message">Please add a Product to get started!</p>}
{
  props.options.map((option, index) => (
<div key={option}>
    <Option
      optionText={option}      
      count= {index + 1}
      handleDeleteOption={props.handleDeleteOption}
    />
    <Option       
      colorText = {props.colors[index]}
      count= {index + 1}
      handleDeleteOption={props.handleDeleteOption}
    />
   <Option       
      priceText = {props.prices[index]}          
      count= {index + 1}
      handleDeleteOption={props.handleDeleteOption}
    />
</div>
  )) 
}
</div>
```

I did it while writing so maybe I forgot some parenthesis or bracket but the idea is only one map and inside that map getting one element each iteration.

This could be much better is the array had an object with 3 properties, one for each type(option, color, price) and then passing object.option, object.color and object.price to each Option component.

In this approach I'm also not taking into account that props.prices[index] or props.colores[index] might not exist, I don't know if that might happen, it was just to show the concept.

Comment: The concept is correct, but I'm confused by the option tags in OPs code. I'm not sure if this would affect the output or the input.